# Evidence of Jesus being either autistic or having difficulty speaking?

Tags: bible

I believe I read somewhere that people who speak in analogies often have a speech impediment or have difficulty speaking.

Is there evidence of this in the Bible?

Comment: "I read somewhere" needs to be refined to include an actual source for this assertion or this question is not clear enough/not specific enough, nor thought out well enough, for this format.  Please find a source for this assertion beyond "I read somewhere" (I'd be interested to see any support for this assertion as well).  I frequently use analogies, but do not have a speech impediment.  Where does that leave me?

Comment: Yeah, we're gonna need a link or something. Any idea at all who might have said it or the title of the book/article? We can help you find it. Seems a spurious claim, nonetheless. I'm not sure a person with a speech impediment would have been able to convince as many people as he did. Remember, there's passages in the Bible where Jesus was annoyed at his followers, so he'd say something to get them all to leave. Doesn't sound like a person who has trouble communicating.

Comment: I don't know about speech impediments, but as for autism, the (admittedly few) autistic people whom I've heard speaking have been less likely than others to use analogies or parables and more likely to just say very explicitly what they mean.

Comment: "Both autistic groups performed worse than controls at complex language tasks such as figurative language, comprehension and inference." ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autism#Communication)) The claim looks backwards to me.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I have googled a lot I can not find a good reference help would be appreciatde.

Comment: Is a question being blasphemous grounds for closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can say with a good degree of confidence that our Lord did not have difficulty speaking. His being the Word of God (John 1:1 ff.) more than mitigates against him having difficulty speaking!

On the other hand, Jesus faced the challenge of speaking to audiences who had ***difficulty listening***. Oh, there was nothing wrong with the acuity of their hearing; rather, there was something wrong with their hearts which prevented them from listening in a way which led to understanding and obedience.

When asked of his disciples why he chose to teach in parables, Jesus said to them,

> “To you it has been granted to know the mysteries of the kingdom of heaven, but to them it has not been granted. For whoever has, to him more shall be given, and he will have an abundance; but whoever does not have, even what he has shall be taken away from him. Therefore I speak to them in parables; because ***while seeing they do not see, and while hearing they do not hear, nor do they understand***. In their case the prophecy of Isaiah is being fulfilled, which says,
>
> ‘You will keep on hearing, but will not understand;
>   You will keep on seeing, but will not perceive;
>   For the heart of this people has become dull,
>   With their ears they scarcely hear,
>   And they have closed their eyes,
>   Otherwise they would see with their eyes,
>   Hear with their ears,
>   And understand with their heart and return,
>   And I would heal them.’
>
> But blessed are your eyes, because they see; and your ears, because they hear. For truly I say to you that many prophets and righteous men desired to see what you see, and did not see it, and to hear what you hear, and did not hear it.
>   Matthew 13:11-16 NASB, my emphasis).

Comment: @William It's OK to accept the answer, even if it is a frame challenge.  (I liked it too).

Comment: William, perhaps you have mistaken Jesus for Moses !